# unable to place the two HTML tables in right position

Tags: html, css

I have created a table using HTML and CSS and as I'm a beginner I'm not getting an way to place the two table in same coordinates.

Here is my html & CSS code for two tables and You can run the code to get the result:

```css
<style>
table{
                width: 50%;
                table-layout: fixed
            }
.table-content{
                height:300px;
                overflow-x:auto;
                margin-top: 0px;
                border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
            }
            th{
                padding: 20px 15px;
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #fff;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            td{
                padding: 15px;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #fff;
                border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
            }
            #table-header{
                background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
            }
            section{
                margin: 50px;
            }
            ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                width: 6px;
            } 
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
            } 
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
             -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
            }
</style>
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="table-header">
            
            <!--Creating The First TAble Of Headings-->
            
            
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Features</th>
                        <th>Fireblade</th>
                        <th>SP</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="table-content">
            
            <!--Creating The Second TAble Of Contents-->
            
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Starting</td>
                        <td>Self Start Only</td>
                        <td>Self Start Only</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Wheels Type</td>
                        <td>Alloy</td>
                        <td>Alloy</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tyre Type</td>
                        <td>Tubeless</td>
                        <td>Tubeless</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Standard Warranty</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ABS</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tachometer</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Low Fuel Warning Lamp</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pilot Lamps</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>LED tail lights</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Projector head light</td>
                        <td>Multi-Reflector Type Angel eye HID Projector</td>
                        <td>Multi-Reflector Type Angel eye HID Projector</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Body Graphics</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Trip Meter</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Clock</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Speedometer</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
       </section>
```

The end result you can see by running the code sample it is giving the exact ouput as the browser. Any response will be greeted THANKYOU!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove "" on top of . it is causing problem to align them.

```css
<style>
table{
                width: 50%;
                table-layout: fixed
            }
.table-content{
                height:300px;
                overflow-x:auto;
                margin-top: 0px;
                border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
            }
            th{
                padding: 20px 15px;
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #fff;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
           .table-header{
               overflow-y: auto;
               height: 200px;
            }
            td{
                padding: 15px;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #fff;
                border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
            }
            #table-header{
                background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
            }
            section{
                margin: 50px;
            }
            ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                width: 6px;
            } 
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
            } 
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
             -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
            }
</style>
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="table-header">
            
            <!--Creating The First TAble Of Headings-->
            
            
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Features</th>
                        <th>Fireblade</th>
                        <th>SP</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
           
  
            
            <!--Creating The Second TAble Of Contents-->
            
           
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Starting</td>
                        <td>Self Start Only</td>
                        <td>Self Start Only</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Wheels Type</td>
                        <td>Alloy</td>
                        <td>Alloy</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tyre Type</td>
                        <td>Tubeless</td>
                        <td>Tubeless</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Standard Warranty</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ABS</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tachometer</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Low Fuel Warning Lamp</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pilot Lamps</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>LED tail lights</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Projector head light</td>
                        <td>Multi-Reflector Type Angel eye HID Projector</td>
                        <td>Multi-Reflector Type Angel eye HID Projector</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Body Graphics</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Trip Meter</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Clock</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Speedometer</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
       </section>
```

Comment: You dont a separate table for header. I just combined the <thead> and <tbody> in a same <table>.

Comment: @Hasant Safder This will lead to remove the scrollbar. If I'm not wrong u are creating the table tag once and closing once but it's not the sollution. I need the scroll bar too

Comment: @HasantSafder Can u plz highlight the changes you have made

Comment: @Stone yes i combined <thead> and <tbody> in same >table>. Then for scroll i added a new css for class "table-header"
           .table-header{
               overflow-y: auto;
               height: 200px;
            }

Comment: @Hasnat Safder thnks bro it helped but can u give some hint what "overflow-y: auto; height: 200px" actually did

Comment: @Stone Height: 200px will limit the table height to 200 pixels (px). The overflow-y: auto means that on y coordinates(vertically) i want auto overflow (which adds scroll bar). You can learn more about overflow in 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left;` and this will resolve your issue.

```css
table{
                width: 50%;
                table-layout: fixed;
                  float: left;
            }
.table-content{
                height:300px;
                overflow-x:auto;
                margin-top: 0px;
                border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
            }
            th{
                padding: 20px 15px;
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #fff;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            td{
                padding: 15px;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #fff;
                border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
            }
            #table-header{
                background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
            }
            section{
                margin: 50px;
            }
            ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                width: 6px;
            } 
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
            } 
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
             -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
            }
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="table-header">
            
            <!--Creating The First TAble Of Headings-->
            
            
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Features</th>
                        <th>Fireblade</th>
                        <th>SP</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="table-content">
            
            <!--Creating The Second TAble Of Contents-->
            
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Starting</td>
                        <td>Self Start Only</td>
                        <td>Self Start Only</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Wheels Type</td>
                        <td>Alloy</td>
                        <td>Alloy</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tyre Type</td>
                        <td>Tubeless</td>
                        <td>Tubeless</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Standard Warranty</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ABS</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tachometer</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Low Fuel Warning Lamp</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                        <td>YES</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pilot Lamps</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>LED tail lights</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Projector head light</td>
                        <td>Multi-Reflector Type Angel eye HID Projector</td>
                        <td>Multi-Reflector Type Angel eye HID Projector</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Body Graphics</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Trip Meter</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Clock</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                        <td align="center" style="text-align:center; font-size:150%; font-weight:bold; color:green;">&#10004;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Speedometer</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                        <td>Digital</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
       </section>
```

Comment: Can u plz see your code output bu running it here it's not giving it's wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best approach to make two tables and sync between them, if you want to make a table with fixed header and scrollable table body content then have a look here

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
}
section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:800px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>
            Table attribute name
            <div>Table attribute name</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Value
            <div>Value</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            Description
            <div>Description</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the alignment of a table according to surrounding text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>bgcolor</td>
          <td>rgb(x,x,x), #xxxxxx, colorname</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the background color for a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>border</td>
          <td>1,""</td>
          <td>Specifies whether the table cells should have borders or not</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellpadding</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellspacing</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>frame</td>
          <td>void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>rules</td>
          <td>none, groups, rows, cols, all</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>summary</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>width</td>
          <td>pixels, %</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```